# Not seeing headers in HTTP response received from the server

Tags: angular5

In the following code, I was expecting that I'll see all the headers and the message body.

However, I don't. What am I doing wrong? I want to extract `Set-Cookie` header from the response and store it.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
  withCredentials: true, 
  observe: 'response' as 'response'
};


public signinUser(user:UserSigninInfo):any{
    let signinInfo= new UserSignin(user);
    let body = JSON.stringify(signinInfo);
    return this.http.post(this.SIGNIN_USER_URL,body,httpOptions)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

This is the code which calls the above `signinUser` function:

```
return this.bs.signinUser(user).subscribe((res)=>console.log('response from server:',res) );
```

But in browser's console, I see the following

[image]

If I check the `Network` tab of a browser, I can see that the following headers were sent to `200 OK`.

Why am I not seeing them in my console print and how could I see them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the headers, I had to access the 'headers' within the response. The headers are lazily evaluated it seems, thus they are not visible. The list of headers in the response could be received using `res.headers.keys()`. I could print the list of headers using the code

```
return this.bs.signinUser(user).subscribe((res:HttpResponse<any>)=>{console.log('response from server:',res);
      console.log('response headers',res.headers.keys())
    } );
```

It printed

```
response from server: 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:9000/ws/users/signin", ok: true, type: 4, body: {…} }
main.bundle.js:1127:13
response headers 
[…]
​
0: "Content-Length"
​
1: "Content-Security-Policy"
​
2: "Content-Type"
​
3: "Date"
​
4: "Referrer-Policy"
​
5: "X-Content-Type-Options"
​
6: "X-Frame-Options"
​
7: "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies"
​
8: "X-XSS-Protection"
​
length: 9
```